# ipad 4 mini: stuck in "activation error", unable to access device

Tags: ios, ipad, jailbreak

I have a very old ipad 4 mini (9.3.1). I got it from a friend. I factory reset it and now when I power it on, I enter my passcode and the iPad just says "We're sorry, we are unable to continue with your activation at this time. Activation could not be completed. Please restore the iPad and install the latest version of iPadOS."

[image]

I cannot get past this screen. I can't access anything in the actual iPad. I can't open Safari or iTunes or any apps or anything. It isn't asking me for a password or passcode after I unlock it, it just tells me it's unable to be activated.

I can't install the latest version of iOS because this ipad is so old it has to be updated via itunes, it can't be updated wirelessly. As stated above, I cannot access iTunes on my iPad, and when I connect the iPad to my PC, my PC gives me the same message.

Can I still jailbreak this ipad somehow even though it's very outdated? or am I shit outta luck?